# Sending multipart/form-data using GraphQL API in .NetCore

Tags: .net-core, graphql, asp.net-core-webapi, graphql-dotnet, apollo-angular

I'm trying to upload the user avatar of .png/jpeg/.jpg file types from angular client to .netCore server application using GraphQL API.
I managed to send the image to be uploaded in a request of content type `multipart/form-data` from client-side.
But getting a 400 Error from the API server saying the content-type is not supported.

Error message is as follows:

> message: "Invalid 'Content-Type' header: non-supported media type.
> Must be of 'application/json', 'application/graphql' or 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'. See: [http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/."](http://graphql.org/learn/serving-over-http/.%22)

I'm trying to implement the mutation like this.

```
FieldAsync<StringGraphType>(
            "testImageUpload",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(
                new QueryArgument<StringGraphType> { Name = "testArg" },
                new QueryArgument<UploadGraphType> { Name = "file" }
                ),
            resolve: async context =>
            {
                var testArg = context.GetArgument<string>("testArg");
                var file = context.GetArgument<IFormFile>("file");

                try
                {
                    return await uploaderService().UploadImage(file);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    context.Errors.Add(new ExecutionError("Something happened!"));
                    return context.Errors;
                }
            });
```

I'm using  [GraphQL.net](https://graphql-dotnet.github.io/docs/getting-started/introduction) and [GraphQL.Upload.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GraphQL.Upload.AspNetCore/) for supporting multipart files.

Sample mutation will be like this:

```
mutation testImageUpload($testArg: String, $file: Upload) {
  fileUpload{
    testImageUpload(testArg: $testArg, file: $file)
  }
}
```

Can anybody suggest to me how to make the .NetCore webAPI application accept `multipart/form-data`.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I, too, ran into this issue. The answer lies within your `Startup.cs` file.

First, the reason for which the "Invalid 'Content-Type' header" appears even while using GraphQL.Upload is because (at the time of this answer) the GraphQL.net middleware only checks for the three different Content-Type headers and errors out if none of those match. [See GitHub](https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/server/blob/master/src/Transports.AspNetCore/GraphQLHttpMiddleware.cs)

As for the solution, you haven't shared any of your `Startup.cs` file so I'm not sure what yours looks like. I'll share the relevant pieces of mine.

You'll need to add the service and the middleware.

The service:

```
services.AddGraphQLUpload()
  .AddGraphQL((options, provider) =>
  {
  ...
  });
```

If you're using a endpoints to map to a middleware, you'll need to add the `UseGraphQLUpload` middleware, then map your endpoint.

Example:

```
  app.UseGraphQLUpload<YourSchema>("/api/graphql", new 
  GraphQLUploadOptions {
    UserContextFactory = (ctx) => new GraphQlUserContext(ctx.User)
  });
  app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
  {
    // map HTTP middleware for YourSchema at path api/graphql
    endpoints
      .MapGraphQL<YourSchema, GraphQLMiddleware<YourSchema>>("api/graphql")
      .RequireAuthorization();
    ...
    // Additional endpoints
    ...
   }
```

Everything else looks fine to me.